# PySimpleDMX doesn't know own class

Tags: python, serial-communication

I've been trying to get this module working but for some reason it looks like it doesn't know its own classes

This is my code:

```py
    import pysimpledmx

    mydmx = pysimpledmx.DMXConnection(3)
```

This is the code I need to get from PySimpleDMX:

```py
    class DMXConnection(object):
      def __init__(self, comport = None):
        '''
        On Windows, the only argument is the port number. On *nix, it's the path to the serial device.
        For example:
            DMXConnection(4)              # Windows
            DMXConnection('/dev/tty2')    # Linux
            DMXConnection("/dev/ttyUSB0") # Linux
        '''
        self.dmx_frame = [0] * DMX_SIZE
        try:
          self.com = serial.Serial(comport, baudrate = COM_BAUD, timeout = COM_TIMEOUT)
        except:
          com_name = 'COM%s' % (comport + 1) if type(comport) == int else comport
          print "Could not open device %s. Quitting application." % com_name
          sys.exit(0)

        print "Opened %s." % (self.com.portstr)
```

The error I get when i want to use the DMXConnection:

```
AttributeError: module 'pysimpledmx' has no attribute 'DMXConnection'
```

But as you can see, DMXConnection is an attribute of pysimpledmx.
I've tried to reinstall the module with PIP, but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you name your script `pysimpledmx.py`, by any chance?

Comment: You mean the file I'm working in myself? No. I understand that if I did, it wouldn't work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an abandoned **Python 2** package, either install it and use it with Python 2 version or copy [the module](https://github.com/c0z3n/pySimpleDMX/blob/master/pysimpledmx/pysimpledmx.py) file in your project and try to debug it.

Comment: I hate to say it but you're right. Luckly I found a revised version. Thank you!